# Issues in porting c/c++ code to VxWorks

Tags: c++, vxworks

I need to port a c/c++ codebase that already supports Linux/Mac, to VxWorks. I am pretty new to VxWorks. Could you let me know what are the possible issues that could arise?

Answer (score 3):

We recently did the opposite conversion - we ported code from a PowerPC machine running VxWorks to an Intel system running Linux.  I don't remember hitting many snags as far as the differences between the operating systems. Obviously any call to an OS specific API will have to change and we were not making extensive use of these functions.

Our biggest problem was not the difference between the operating systems, but rather the difference between PowerPC and Intel hardware.  PowerPC is Big Endian and Intel is Little Endian. Our software is written in C and made many assumptions as to the order of bytes and this was an absolute nightmare to get it working smoothly again.  There were literally hundreds of structures that defined bitfields and needed to be re-ordered to work correctly. We ended up implementing a #pragma in GCC that reversed these bitfields at their definition (#pragma reverse_bitfields).

Answer (score 2):

Much depends on which version of VxWorks you're targeting, and the actual target processor itself.  One thing you will have to deal with is that there is no paged memory system or virtual memory--you have what's there.  The environment itself is far more constrained than a linux system.  Sometimes the work involved in porting applications goes all the way back to the architecture level because resources are not as unlimited as they are in linux.

Some other tips:

- license vxworks such that you have the source code available
- use a real, physical target as soon as possible in the development cycle; do not count on the simulators accurately emulating the target
- use TSRs (technical support requests) as necessary; I don't know how they structure the purchase of the right to create TSRs, but don't let anybody cheap out on these

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what processor you are running with VxWorks endianness, structure packing, and memory alignment could all be issues.  The last time I used VxWorks it supported a pthreads, sockets, and mutex layer that mimicked the unix environments easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell, without knowing more about the application that you're porting: What linux libraries and api calls does it use? Is it self-contained, or does it rely on slews of linux command-line tools and scripts to do its job?

As Average says, endianness can cause you way more problems than you expect - particularly if you're not prepared for it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The application uses pthread, socket library, critical section and mutex handling APIs. Could you let me know if they will arise any issues in porting to VxWorks?